# i have 3 columns , total count , pass count , and fail count , how do i write formula in SQL or SPL if fail count is > 8% its development error

Tags: sql, splunk-query

i have 3 columns , total count , pass count , and fail count , how do i write formula in SQL or SPL if fail count is > 8% it is development error?

sample input -
pass count - 3900 , 5500 , 2500
total count - 3920, 5700, 3000
fail count - 20 , 200 , 500
formula for
if fail count is more then 8% its sends dev error.

Comment: 8% of what?  Please clarify the question, provide sample input, and provide the desired output.

Comment: pass count  totalcount  failcount
 3900  3920  20
 5500  5700  200
 2500  3000  500
sample of input.if fail count is more then 8% its sends dev error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sends dev error' - sends to where and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple arithmetic to calculate percentage then apply filter criteria to calculated field, like:

```
SELECT Counts.*, [FailCount]/[TotalCount]*100 AS PctFail
FROM Counts
WHERE ((([FailCount]/[TotalCount]*100)>8));
```

Build a report to show that dataset.